# SqlDataReader Close takes 10+ seconds - why?

Tags: ado.net, sqldatareader

I have a case where on a pretty regular select the call to SqlDataReader.Close() takes 10+ seconds to return. The only thing unusual is the select returns 20 rows but in this case none of the rows are read.

```
DbDataReader reader = (DbDataReader) cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default);
reader.MoveNext();
var row = de.Current;

// lots of other code that does not touch this.
reader.Close();
```

Why does it take so long? And more important, what can I do to make it fast?

Comment: is it a lengthy query that requires a lot of processing?

Comment: All the orders in Northwind so nothing complex and not that long. Plus it's the Close() that's taking the time.

Comment: you set a timer around reader.Close(); to confirm?  Im thinking that something is waiting to complete before it is closed.

Comment: I used dotTrace at first to find it. But I then set a breakpoint on the call and when I told the debugger to step over, that took 10 seconds. I don't have any other threads hitting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find out what/why this is occurring. So on the call to close my object, I create a worker thread and have that close the data reader and connection. I then return immediately so the user sees no delay. Works fine.

**Update:** As per [SqlDataReader.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx) it can be reduced by calling the Cancel method of the associated SqlCommand object before calling the Close method. h/t [Lingaraj Mishra](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/lingaraj%20mishra/?ws=usercard-mini)